# Problem with fetching and loop between data

Tags: reactjs

I want to loop between the data from this api,but i can't show them in return(doesn't show something)

```
const Api_Endpoint = 'https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers'
       const [beers, setBeers] = useState([])
        const [description, setDescription] = useState([])
        const [img, setImg] = useState([])
    
        useEffect(() => {
            fetch(Api_Endpoint)
                .then(results => results.json())
                .then(data => {
                    setBeers(data[0].name)
                    setDescription(data[0].description)
                    setImg(data[0].image_url)
                })
    
    
        }, [])
```

i did it with one useState before,but how can i do that for multiple useState?

I write it like this:

```
return (
      <div>
     {value => {
                  return value.beers.map(product => {
                    return <Beer key={product.id} product={product.name} />;
                  });
                }}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: do you mean just loop the data and update the state?

Comment: Yes,i've tried to loop with several ways,but it didnt work,i can show one image,one name,...but i want to loop and maping between all data

Comment: I  put my answer  hope it gonna help you

Comment: Yes,thanks,but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,
Here is [Codesandbox.io link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-pare-h9zrs?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Api_Endpoint = 'https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers';

const App = () => {
  const [beers, setBeers] = useState(null);
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(null);
  const [img, setImg] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    fetch(Api_Endpoint)
      .then((results) => results.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setBeers(data[0].name)
        setDescription(data[0].description)
        setImg(data[0].image_url);
      })
  }, []);
  
  if ((beers || description  || img) === null) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{beers}</h1>
      <p>{description}</p>
      <img src={img} alt={description}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: thanks but this code just show one item and wont return all of them

Comment: You can try this one: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-hofstadter-7ls7y

Comment: you can remove the null and just do the !beers as a shorter version

Answer (score 0):

maybe do something like this

```
setBeers(data.map(d => d.name)
setDescription(data.map(d => d.description)
setImg(data.map(d => d.image_url)
```

another thing I suggest to you is that try to do it in one state to split them  will make everything more difficult to update
and when you map on the state you need to do it to each state instead of one
and you can't tell if the image_url is belongs to the right place in case you do something
and then you just need to do something like this

```
setBeers([...data])
```

destructuring is here to make sure the state will update

Comment: @Negin msr hope this. answer helps you